# Is there a name for the class of infinite groups with no proper infinite quotients?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there is there a name for the class of infinite groups with no proper infinite quotients?

I came across this paper http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160210604/pdf and the author calls them "just-infinite groups". Is this the contemporary designation of these groups?

Comment: They are called finite groups. Every infinite group has an infinite quotient..itself.

Comment: The definition of "[just infinite](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Just_infinite_group)" that I am familiar with is  "infinite, but every *proper* quotient group is finite".  Note that the class you want contains finite groups, which are not just infinite.

Comment: @Jake: The cited paper concerns groups where the _only_ infinite quotient is the entire group -- that is, every _nontrivial_ normal subgroup has finite index.

Comment: I suspect that the question is missing the word "proper" and is meant to be " the class of groups with no infinite proper quotients". Then indeed, such groups are called "just infinite" and this is the name currently used for such groups.

Comment: My mistake. I was asking for the class of infinite groups with no nontrivial normal subgroups with infinite index. Thanks very much studiosus! I am going to edit the question so as not to confuse anyone in the future.